# Which query injection breaks this SQL if input is validated again regex?

Tags: sql-injection

SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMN_NAME = {INPUT};

I don't have a connection directly to a database, so I have to send the query as string. I will validate the input value against this pattern "[a-zA-Z]\s[a-zA-Z]", so I haven't found a way to break this query.

Comment: If your query accepts a input from end user then it's vulnerable to SI

Comment: my pattern reject "a b' OR 1=1 --"

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant [a-zA-Z]\s[a-zA-Z].

Seems to works on all examples of this page:
http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html

Comment: You should share your regular expression check because it seems really strange for column names.